# How to make a small square inside a rectangle having text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, rectangles

I have a screenshot below which I have replicated in HTML & CSS.

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/115/embedded/result/) for the above screenshot. I have used Bootstrap 4 in order to make the table.

The snippets of HTML and CSS codes which I have used in order to make the rows are:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="number">Number</th>
                <th scope="col" class="table2">Table</th>
                <th scope="col" class="status">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="left">Eve Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived">Items Received</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived">Items Received</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td class="right-itemswaiting"> Items Waiting</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Jack Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">14</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-unpaid">Unpaid</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table td,
.table th {
    border-top: none! important;
    padding-left: 3%;
}

.table thead th {
    border-bottom: none! important;
}

.table td.left {
    padding-right: 32%;
}

.body-manage-attendees tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees .number {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table1 {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table2 {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .status {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-bill {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-nobill {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the CSS codes above so that square box (marked with arrow in the screen-shot above) shows up inside the colored rectangle.

Comment: Does this square has to be functional, as in checkbox-checked/unchecked? Or is it just a static box?

Comment: @kevinb. No, it doesn't have to be functional. It is just a static box.

Comment: I have added it in an answer below

Comment: @kevinb. Did you add something ? I can't see anything.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the answer later than my comment. Should be added now :) let me know if you need something more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/137/)
I have added some CSS rules and updated your HTML structure for the colored rectangles.

```css
// General CSS
.nav-top-searchbar {
    position: relative;
}

#ellipsis {
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 43px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ellipsis:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#ellipsis:focus+.dropdown {
    display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    /* padding-left: 2%; */
    position: absolute;
    /* height: 150px; */
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888;
    top: 2px;
}

.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 3px;
}

.table td,
.table th {
    border-top: none! important;
    padding-left: 3%;
}

.table thead th {
    border-bottom: none! important;
}

.table td.left {
    padding-right: 32%;
}

.dropdown a {
    color: #676767;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees .number {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table1 {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table2 {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .status {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-bill {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-nobill {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-unapid {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-itemsreceived {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #10314C;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-itemswaiting {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #10314C;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-unpaid {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1173B7;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-top-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0% 2.5%;
    background: rgb(16, 49, 76);
    align-items: center;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right-itemsreceived span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="number">Number</th>
                <th scope="col" class="table2">Table</th>
                <th scope="col" class="status">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Eve Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived">Items Received</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived"><div class="square"></div><span>Items Received</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td class="right-itemswaiting"> Items Waiting</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Jack Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">14</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-unpaid">Unpaid</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks kevin. I am integrating it into my code. Will give you a shout if I have any question related to that.

Comment: I have a similar question. I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/156/embedded/result/) for the code you have sent. I am wondering if there is any way in css or jquery if I hit or click on `items waiting` row, `items waiting` text should be replaced by `items received` with the switch in square boxes.

Comment: Try to make a new question out of it, as this is a seperate question. Post a link here afterwards if you want me to take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

```
.body-manage-attendees .right-itemsreceived::before {

   content: url(image.jpg); /* Insert content image here*/
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start of by using the **div Function**

So here is a Exemple

```css
.square {
  width: 50%;
  background: #000;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
     
</div>
```

### So Here is a Exemple

and now with your Code : You can see Here on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/130/)

ofc you can play around with the code and add boostrap this is just to get you **started**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="number">Number</th>
                <th scope="col" class="table2">Table</enter code hereth>
                <th scope="col" class="status">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="left">Eve Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived">
                <input  type ="checkbox"/><span style="padding-left:15px">Items Received<span></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived">
                <input  class="right-itemsreceived" type ="checkbox"/><span style="padding-left:15px">Items Received<span></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>

                <td class="right-itemswaiting"><input type ="checkbox"/><span style="padding-left:15px"> Items Waiting</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Jack Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">14</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-unpaid"><input type ="checkbox"/><span style="padding-left:15px">Unpaid</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Just add these changes to your code to add checkbox to your table data

or just look here https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/151/ for the demo